# is figaro available as a command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems

figaro gem for Ruby on Rails.

when I used this command as instructed on Figaro's GitHub README,

```
$ figaro heroku:set -e production
-bash: figaro: command not found
```

i try many different ways using suggestion on the net (StackOverFlow and everywhere else).

Does installing figaro gem really install figaro command?

I'm using Figaro 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it does: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/blob/master/figaro.gemspec#L22

i assume you have installed the gem via bundler and probably need to `bundle exec figaro [...]`

Comment: must use "bundle exec"?    that simple?  thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: is that a question or an answer? did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes it answered my question. Thanks